# How correct print text from variable

Tags: vim

I have a variable that holds the string returned from `system()`.

But escape sequences don't work.

I tried putting the string in register `@j` but the result was the same.

If I use a simple string:

```
 let l:my_var = "hello\nworld"
```

all work!

How I may adjust the text to fit?

> vim 8.2 (2019 Dec 12)

`\n` doesn't work:

[image: \n don't work]

Comment: A bit of explanation of what's going on in that screenshot would be useful. Anyway, if you expect a multiline return value from the external command, then you should use `:help systemlist()` which gives you a list, much easier to use in the context of scripting than a string with `\n`s.

Comment: Sorry. I have bad English.

Comment: Yes I wanna show multiline string in window vim (but \n don't work). I get this string from system() function. This string holds output SQL command (show create table name). I tried systemlist() but get only two node. This don't work